# Dropdown of associated entities using MVC 5 and Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

I'm using MVC 5 and Entity Framework. I have 2 entities, a Person and a PersonType. I have created an Association between them, so that a Person has a PersonType property :

```
namespace Test.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public virtual PersonType personType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This code was generated by the Entity Data Model (.edmx).

In the controller, I then add all the PersonTypes to a ViewBag, so that they can be added to a dropdown control in the page :

```
ViewBag.PersonTypeList = new SelectList(db.PersonTypes, "Id", "Description");
```

The model for the page is set to 'Person' and contains a dropdown :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.personType, "Person Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.personType.Id, ViewBag.PersonTypeList as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.personType.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

This seems to work OK, but when it comes to saving the Person it seems to be trying to create a new PersonType using the Id I selected, rather than simply referencing the one that exists in the PersonType table already? Am I doing this wrong? Many Thanks

Comment: I would imagine this is down to your insert/upsert method. You need to review the logic for that; I would assume you're probably not passing down the ID value to your method so it is assuming that the type selected is new and therefore adding it to the database, but this is blind assumption having not seen your code of course :-)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: Quick shout out to @Dave for answering my question with his question. Seeing how you linked your dropdown list to a ViewBag property is the first time I've run into that approach. I had viewed 3-4 answers that were linking the dropdown to a property in Model -- none of which worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set up the relation using an .edmx file, you should also get a FK property, e.g. `myPerson.PersonType_Id` (usually the name is `{classname}_{PKfieldname}`).
If that field already exists, assign the chosen ID from the dropdownlist to that property.

**However, there is a bug in the edmx generation.**

I noticed this about a year ago, and it only occurs under very specific circumstances.

When you set up a relation via an .edmx (Right click > Add > Association...), you will get a window asking you to select the two entities you wish to relate.

[image: Random example image found online.]

**For 1-to-many relations, you must make sure the MANY-entity is on the right side of that window.** (just like in the image above)

The wizard perfectly allows you to do the opposite (basically setting up a many-to-1, if you read it from left to right). If you do this, that secondary FK field I mentioned will not be set up.

When that field is not set up, and you try to add it via the `.PersonType` field instead, it seems that EF often tries to create the object.

To fix this, you'll have to remove the association, and add it again when the MANY entity is on the right side of the window.

For your case, that means `PersonType` should be on the left, `Person` should be on the right.

When that is done, have your dropdownlist fill in the `PersonType_Id` field (should be an int if you use default PKs). Leave the `PersonType` property blank, and save the `Person` object you just created.
EF should then correctly look for an existing `PersonType` instead of trying to create a new one.

Can you confirm if this solution works for you?

Comment: Hi - I think it was the FK Property bit I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to see it helped :) I spent ages looking for this bug, as it seems to be unintended and counterintuitive behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your razor you have referenced
    model=>model.personType.Id 
in dropdown which seems to be problem. Add another property 
    personTypeId 
in class Person which obviously mapped to foreign key in person table. And edit model=>model.personType.Id to model=>model.personTypeId 
in dropdownlist in razor.

Comment: While you're correct in identifying the problem, OP can't just change his class, as he is generating everything from an .edmx file. (Well, he *can* change it, but it'd be a temporary fix until a new model was generated)